# Quadratic model as linear decrease in proportions

Tags: regression, probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Assume $Y_i <= X_i$ for all $i$. The conditional expectation of our data was found to satisfy

$E[Y|X=x] = a1*x-a2*x^2$

to very good accuracy for a large range, with $0<a2<a1<1$. Re-arranging the equation turns into

$\frac{E[Y|X=x]}{x} = a1-a2*x$

Or, point into words, the conditional expected value of Y as a function of X, as a fraction of x, decreases linearly as a function of x.

Is there a probabilistic model that would have explain this behavior? Originally this was found just by regression, but the second equation seems to imply a probability model might be able to explain a linear decrease in proportions behavior.

Comment: There are a variety of possible models that could look very like your quadratic model over some range of $x$.